# Find maximum of all data present in each columns in a pig table using pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

Input Format:

```
Year_2010 , Year_2009, Year_2008

1.2, 2.4, 3.5
3.4, 3.8, 5.7
4.5, 5.6, 3.4
3.7, 2.6, 4.8
```

I have tried the following script and it works for 1 column.

```
A = Load '/Year.csv' Using PigStorage(',') as (Year_2010:double,Year_2009:double,Year_2008:double); 
B = group A ALL; 
max = Foreach B generate group,MAX(A.Year_2010);
```

Expected Output:

```
Year_2010, Year_2009, Year_2008

4.5, 5.6, 5.7
```

Comment: A = Load '/Year.csv' Using PigStorage(',') as (Year_2010:double,Year_2009:double,Year_2008:double);
    B = group A ALL;
max = Foreach B generate group,MAX(A.Year_2010);


**I knew this will work for one column but finding it for three column i am not sure what to try**

Comment: Ok thats a start and you are on the right track.Just apply the MAX for all the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [MAX](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#MAX).GROUP before applying the MAX on the columns.

```
A = Load '/Year.csv' Using PigStorage(',') as (Year_2010:double,Year_2009:double,Year_2008:double); 
B = GROUP A ALL;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE MAX(A.Year_2010),MAX(A.Year_2009),MAX(A.Year_2008);
DUMP C;
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Getting an error as follows :                                                                                                                
Error: Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.MAX as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.

Comment: Check your data,looks like you have a space after ','.Check the datatype you are loading into.It must be double.Also MAX should be in caps.Use "C" instead of max for relation